# IIS not displaying Default sites

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-7

I am using IIS7.5 in Windows 7

I installed the IIS into my system but when I go to the IIS Manager, I don't see any "Default Web Site". I also don't see any "DefaultAppPool".

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the IIS Manager, what nodes do you see under the top-level node in the far left? It sounds like you are saying there is an Application Pools node and a Sites node with no child nodes?

---------EDIT---------

It sounds like the Windows Process Activation Service is the problem.

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistainstall/thread/b86da8a7-2c8c-4c28-9848-4f7989da09fe

MS KB #930911

Comment: Yes. I just have the top level nodes and no children nodes. I dont even have the Windows Process Activation Service installed. Please help.

Comment: As I read the MS forums post, the solution should be to uninstall IIS completely along with the Windows Process Activation Service (if applicable) then reinstall IIS and see if the WAS service shows up along with the app pool and default site. I have resolved similar IIS issues this way. For example, in our ASP.NET app, if you miss a dependency at the time of installation, you may have to uninstall/reinstall IIS to undo the damage. So the short answer is clean up and start over with IIS. You also may want to check the event log for .NET, W3SVC, MSI Installer and WAS errors.